# Slideshow and Image Styles. Looks very different in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8, drupal-7

On Firefox all images are stretched to 650x300 But in IE8 all images are only stretched to vertically be 300px high. They are not horizontally resized.

Using the following modules/library I've created a simple slideshow. However, it looks different in Firefox and IE.

- http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow
- http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel
- http://drupal.org/project/libraries

What am I doing wrong? I've cleared the cache in both browsers.

For some reason IE appends the following to the IMG tag complete="complete" jquery1358921313918="6" Could that be doing it? By the way, even though in IE the image width and height in the source are 650 and 300, that is not what they are displaying as... The height IS 300 but the width is not 600px... From the source:

Firefox:

```
<img width="650" height="300" src="URL/sites/default/files/styles/homepage-slideshow/public/…
```

IE:

```
<img width="650" height="300" src="URL/sites/default/files/styles/homepage-slideshow/public/…; complete="complete" jquery1358921313918="6"/>
```